# Submit book to Google eBookStore

Tags: google-books

This might be the wrong location for this question but is there an API to submit books to Google eBookStore?

We have a client that want's to allow users to publish their own books to the ebookstore but everything I've read only allows searching and purchasing but not uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is not a publisher, your client needs to partner with a publisher of vanity (or print-on-demand) books that makes titles available via Google Books.

Comment: our client is a publisher and i guess i'd like to know how to make books available via google books before i ask them for help